# i need to take an mpir integer and output it into a char buffer

Tags: c++, gmp, mpir

i have recently installed mpir and have the following code (c++) visual studio.

```
char buffer[100]
mpz_t x;

mpz_set_str(x, "7612058254738945", 10);
```

I would like to print x into the buffer. used to use sprint but there does not seem to be any sprint for mpir

thanks

david

Answer (score 4):

You can use [mpz_get_str](http://www.ontko.com/pub/rayo/gmp/gmp_6.html) along with sprintf(%s specifier) or strcat or someother string utility.

From the same page for length of this number

> To find out the right amount of space to provide for str, use
>   mpz_sizeinbase (op, base) + 2. The two extra bytes are for a possible
>   minus sign, and for the terminating null character.

Comment: And there is `gmp_sprintf`, according to section 10.2 of http://mpir.org/mpir-1.3.1.pdf